# If string equals something, open a file - batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that launches a specific program depending on what string I insert, this is what I have:

```
@echo off
color 2
echo Welcome Frej
SET /P %do%=What do you want to do today?
IF %do%=Minecraft (cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Minecraft 
start MinecraftLauncher.exe
PAUSE
exit
)
IF %do%=Code (cd C:/Users/ItzBenteThePig/Desktop/eclipse
start eclipse.exe
PAUSE
exit
)
IF %do%=Bukkit (cd C:/Users/ItzBenteThePig/Desktop/eclipse-bukkit
start eclipse.exe
PAUSE
exit 
)
```

But it doesn't really seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "doesn't really seem to work" In what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code corrected:

```
@echo off
color 2
echo Welcome Frej
SET /P "Action=What do you want to do today? "
IF "%Action%"=="Minecraft" (
    cd /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Minecraft"
    start MinecraftLauncher.exe
    PAUSE
    exit
)
IF "%Action%"=="Code" (
    cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\eclipse"
    start eclipse.exe
    PAUSE
    exit
)
IF "%Action%"=="Bukkit" (
    cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\eclipse-bukkit"
    start eclipse.exe
    PAUSE
    exit 
)
```

For comparing two strings you must use `==` and not just `=`.

It is often advisable to use surrounding quotes on string comparisons, especially in this case where user of batch file simply can press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all resulting in variable not being defined if not already defined before user prompt with a default value.

After `set /P` the name of the variable should be specified and not the reference to value of a variable (in most cases).

`do` is a keyword in command line syntax. Do not use a predefined keyword as name for a variable.

Executing `set` without any parameter in a command prompt window results in getting displayed all predefined environment variables for the current user account. It is advisable to make use of those predefined variables.

The directory separator is `\` on Windows and not `/` as on Unix/Linux/Mac. Well, Windows command processor replaces automatically all `/` by `\`, but better is nevertheless to use the right directory separator.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `color /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`

By the way: Do you know that it is possible to define a hotkey for shortcut on desktop or in Windows start menu to quickly start an application with pressing this key combination. Ctrl+Alt+Letter is a good method to start quickly an application. Shortcut to Minecraft with hotkey Ctrl+Alt+M defined in properties of the shortcut makes it possible to quickly start Minecraft.